# Proving $S$ is an ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Hope this is not duplicated.

> Problem: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ as an identity such that $1\neq 0$ and $1+1=0$. Denote $S=\left\{a\in R: a^2=0\right\}$. Show that $S$ is an ideal of $R$.

Firstly, why we call $1$ as an identity (as the ring has 2 identities? So the default for this is the multiplicative inverse?). I know that the definition of (left) Ideal is that I need to prove (not sure though)

> 1. $(S,+)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$
> 2. $\forall r\in R,\forall s\in S$, we must have that $rs\in S$

I can't fully prove the first one. For the second one, we have that as $R$ is commutative
$$(rs)^2=r^2s^2=r^2\cdot 0=r^2(0+0)=r^2\cdot 0+r^2\cdot 0\Longrightarrow r^2\cdot 0=0,$$
and actually any $r\in R$, $r\cdot 0=r\cdot 0+ r\cdot 0$ so $r\cdot 0=0$. Thus, we have the second property.

For the first one, we have $0\in S$ by the same argument as above so $S\neq\phi$. Now, I need to show the additive subgroup that

> 1. If $a,b\in S$ then $a+b\in S$
> 2. $\forall a\in S$, $-a\in S$

It would be make sense to me if I can show $ab=0$ if $a,b\in S$, since this will imply the two properties above, that is
$(a+b)^2=a^2+ab+ab+b^2=0$ . This can be done if I can show the second, if we let $b=-a$, we have $0=(a+b)^2=a^2+ab+ab+b^2=b(b+a+a)=ab$. However, I don't know how to show the second?

Comment: \emptyset $\emptyset$ or \varnothing $\varnothing$, not \phi $\phi$ for the empty set

Answer (score 2):

You have almost done it.

Writing $(a+b)^2=a^2+ab+ab+b^2=0+ab+ab+0=ab+ab$, we can now use the fact that $1+1=0$. In the statement of the question, you are given that $1+1=0$, and we haven't used this yet, so it would make sense to try and use it.

$ab+ab=ab(1+1)=ab\cdot 0=0$ so then $(a+b)^2=0$ and $S$ is closed under addition.

In response to your first comment, we almost always write $1$ to be the multiplicative identity and $0$ to be the additive identity, so whenever additive or multiplicative is not specified, that is the assumption we make.

Comment: Oh, thak you so much.

Answer (score 0):

1 is the identity means that it is the identity wrt multplication.regarding the question, pick two elements $a,b$ of $S$,then $(a+b)^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}+ab+ba$ but $ab=ba$(since the ring is assumed to be commutative),so $(a+b)^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}+ab(1+1)=0+0+0=0$,hence $a+b \in S$.